# Firebase how to get The generated Unique Id when I use the Push function

Tags: android, firebase

I have this little problem: In my Realtime I Have a Child "User" which contains all the different users, every user has a bunch of attributes user (email, phone, name...) I Set it into the Firebase using the push function

```
ref.Child("User").push().setvalue(user)
```

so my problem is how to get The unique Id when I set my user to the realtime

I have already used the query that Listen to child using the email
`datasnapshot.getkey()` , but sometimes it returns the Id that I need =D and sometimes it return The first child User

Any solution guys !
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference userRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 userRef.child("User").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key=datas.getKey();
                }
            }

     @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The above will give you the pushid. The loop will iterate inside the pushid and then using `getKey()` you will be able to get the pushid

Comment: Peter Haddad  I already use this one , but my probleme is sometimes it gave me the key = ID and sometimes it give me The first child "User" ,

Comment: It cannot give you the child user because you are iterating inside the id.  Be sure you are using the for loop because in the question you said `dataSnapshot.getKey()` @user8173031

Answer (score 0):

If you want the push ID when you `setValue()`, do this:

```
DatabaseReference userRef = ref.child("User").push();
String pushId = userRef.getKey();
...
userRef.setValue(user);
```